# Scala Option pattern matching with case class

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, type-inference

I get `error: value id is not a member of Nothing`
with `case Some(x) => x.id`. This should not have evaluated to a `Some` type.

```
case class UserDbEntry(id: Int, username: String)

val users = List()
val lastTableIds = "user.1::paypal.1"
val lastUserId   = lastTableIds.split("::")(0).split("\\.")(1)

//This does not compile
val id = users.lastOption match {
  case Some(x) => x.id
  case None => lastUserId
}

//This compiles
def getLastFetchId(x: Option[UserDbEntry]) = x match {
  case Some(user) => user
  case None => 1
}
```

But with the List defined with an explicit type of `List[UserDbEntry]` this is fine, in that case the compiler infers this successfully. I guess it has to do with compiler inferencing; If I am not wrong. Just that I expected an error in line with x not being a member of type `String` if there was a type mismatch.

What exactly is going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you declare:

```
val users = List()
```

The compiler infers:

```
val users: List[Nothing] = List()
```

`Nothing` does not have an id property. But when you specify that users is a `List[UserDbEntry]` and call `lastOption`, then the compiler can understand that the element within the Option is a `UserDbEntry`, which has an id property, hence compiling just fine. Take into account that an empty List will return `None`, which is an `Option[Nothing]`.

Comment: that explains it; ```None``` being ```Option[Nothing]``` was curious on where that came from. thanks

Comment: Basically one should always specify the `type`  . I think we should avoid the practice of writing code as `val users = List()` . We should be making sure our types at compile time.